# How to paste password to login screen in Hyper-V VM

Tags: hyper-v, copy-paste

I use Hyper-V in my Windows 10 and need to be able to paste passwords into login screens (I use password manager to generate and store strong passwords.)

The login screen ignores Ctrl-V and context menu. How can I enable it?

Comment: Enable guest service in VM settings to copy-paste.

Comment: @Biswa `Guest services` as part of Integration services in VM settings is enabled. Copy paste works well when I'm logged into VM but I need to be able paste password into login screen of guest OS (Win Server 2016 and Win 10 in my case)

Comment: @eXavier Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MikeCole Nope (if I remember well). But I didn't dig much deeper, luckily I haven't been needing this for long time..

Answer (score -1):

Run RegEdit as an administrator.
Browse to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System registry sub key. Double-click the PromptOnSecureDesktop registry entry, and then change the value from 1 to 0, click OK to confirm the change.

From:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975788/guided-help-turn-off-the-secure-desktop-in-windows-7 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975788/guided-help-turn-off-the-secure-desktop-in-windows-7  Follow number 2

Comment: isn't this setting just for UAC?

Comment: This did not allow me to copy/paste the password into the login screen.