# Secure login options for a Windows 10 VM running on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, authentication

I am running a Windows 10 VM using Hyper-V and am attempting to make the Windows login process into the VM more secure. Currently, I am using a local Windows account with an easy to type password.

I have tried using a connected Microsoft account. However, you are unable to use Windows Hello in an enhanced Hyper-V session so my only option is to use my Microsoft account password. I am unable to paste into the password field, my Microsoft account password is complex and stored in a password manager, and typing it each time isn't an option.

I was looking at hardware keys, specifically the [Yubico Login for Windows](https://www.yubico.com/products/services-software/download/computer-login-tools/), but I read it is not compatible with RDP which I believe Hyper-V uses (in a sense). I am willing to purchase a key to experiment but thought I'd look at other options.

I am also considering using Azure AD which appears to allow multi-factor authentication in the free version.

I am looking for advice or affirmation of either of these approaches.

Comment: I find a strong password with special characters to be as good as not when fingerprint or facial reader cannot be used.  I have a particularly strong Microsoft Account password that I constructed so as to be easy to remember. Works well

Comment: In the VM, run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options* and check the value of "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode".  The value here of "Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop" will block pastes. The default is "Prompt for consent for non-Windows binaries". ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/112621-change-uac-prompt-behavior-administrators-windows.html))

Comment: @John the idea is I don't want to have to remember my password. I either want to be able to paste a complex password from my password manager or use dual factor authentication.

Comment: @harrymc The value currently is "Prompt for content for non-Windows binaries" and pastes are getting blocked.

Comment: So this isn't the cause. Try this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090037/copy-and-paste-do-not-work-when-you-connect-to-a-hyper-v-virtual-machi

Comment: @harrymc Thanks but I am running Windows 10 and do not have those options. I am able to paste elsewhere, just not on the login screen.

Comment: Yes, this is rather for Windows Server. Try this : https://superuser.com/questions/1218729/how-to-paste-password-to-login-screen-in-hyper-v-vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I learned:

1. Using a Microsoft connected account with a complex password probably would have worked, even though you cannot paste a complex password into Windows login. However, Hyper-V has a menu option that will type contents of your clipboard so that is a valid option.
2. I was able to join the Windows machines to an Azure AD instance. However, the 2FA options were not available in Azure AD free edition.

My solution was to use [Duo](https://duo.com/) and enable Microsoft RDP in Duo. The name is misleading: it does also provide 2FA for Windows logins when you install their Windows client. This allowed me to use a local Windows account on multiple VMs and have them protected with 2FA through Duo which you can configure to automatically send push notifications to your device. Duo also offers a free version that worked well for me.